# Change MYSQL Query UPDATE to REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

The query seems to be easy enough to convert as I have very specific requirement, if it exists just update else insert. But I am having really hard time converting it..probably because of multiple joins it is using. There is a catch to it though, there is no primary key.I would really appreciate it if someone take a crack at it and make my life easier ... :-)

There are only three columns for the table

```
ASSET_ASSOCIATION
-----------------

ASSET_ID | ASSET_FIELD_ID | ASSET_ASSOCIATED_ID

10        46               15
12        46               37
10        21               8
```

Query I am using is

.....

Is there any hope for me ?? Would really appreciate any help .....

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one statement if there's no unique key. You need to try the update, check if any rows were updated, then insert if necessary.

Comment: Can you create a PK or UNIQUE index?

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the table...

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the **same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index**, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

No primary key or unique index, no `REPLACE`, full stop.

A table without a primary key is (almost always) a huge mistake. Get in touch with the DBA (or someone with sufficient privilege) and let him/her know there is no primary key on the table. S/he will add the primary key without you asking for it.